# Connected components of a closed subset of $\mathbb R^2$ one of whose bounadary is a subset of the other

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Let $K$ be a compact, connected subset of $\mathbb R^2$ which is the closure of its interior. Suppose that there are two connected components $U,V$ of $\mathbb R^2\setminus K$ whose boundaries satisfy $\partial V \subset \partial U$. Must it be the case that $ K$ has a cut point (i.e., there is a point $x \in K$ such that $K \setminus \{x\}$ is not connected)?

Intuitively, it seems like this should be the case (I was not able to think of any examples where it would fail) but I am unable to find a proof. A proof or a reference would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does $\subset$ mean $\subseteq $ or $\subsetneq$?

Comment: I use $A\subset B$ to mean "$A$ is a subset of $B$ (allowed to be equal to all of $B$)".

Answer (score 2):

$S^1$ is compact and connected and is the common boundary of itself and the two components of $\Bbb R^2\setminus S^1$, but it has no cut point.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the condition that $K$ has to be equal to the closure of its interior. I edited the question to reflect this. This rules out examples like the one in your answer.